# Custom Post Type won't Register

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

I'm hoping one of you WP gurus can spot what I am missing. I have a CPT that won't register for some reason. It' virtually identical to another CPT that is registered just fine.

I have a custom post type for cartoon-series with a special-features cpt to go with it. Then I have a movies cpt with movie-special-features. The first three work. movie-special-features does not. I literally cut-and-pasted the special-features code and change the areas that needed to be unique. It just fails to load in the back-end.
I use the same rewrite code for both. Again, special-features works fine. If I use rewrite analyzer on movie-special-features, the analyzer output shows the correct rewrite rule being used, but it is red and crossed-out and says "This query variable is not public and will not be saved" when I hover the mouse over it.

At first I thought it was a rewrite problem, but if I get rid of all rewrite rules pertaining to these two cpts, special-features still works on the back-end (although obviously the path for the post would be wrong), and movie-special-features does not.

Can any of you see something wrong with my cpt code?

Here is my code:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------
// Cartoon Series - cartoon-series
// -----------------------------------------------------
    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Cartoon Series",
        "singular_name" => "Cartoon Series",
        "menu_name" => "Cartoon Series",
        "all_items" => "All Cartoon Series",
        "add_new" => "Add New",
        "add_new_item" => "Add New Cartoon Series",
        "edit" => "Edit",
        "edit_item" => "Edit Cartoon Series",
        "new_item" => "New Cartoon Series",
        "view" => "View",
        "view_item" => "View Cartoon Series",
        "search_items" => "Search Cartoon Series",
        "not_found" => "No Cartoon Series Found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "No Cartoon Series Found in Trash",
        "parent" => "Parent Cartoon Series",
        );

$args = array(
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "has_archive" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "cartoon-series", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "supports" => array( "title", "revisions" )
    );
register_post_type( "cartoon-series", $args );


//==================================================================================
// -----------------------------------------------------
// Special Features - special-features
// -----------------------------------------------------
    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Special Features",
        "singular_name" => "Special Feature",
        "menu_name" => "Special Features",
        "all_items" => "All Special Features",
        "add_new" => "Add New",
        "add_new_item" => "Add New Special Feature",
        "edit" => "Edit",
        "edit_item" => "Edit Special Feature",
        "new_item" => "New Special Feature",
        "view" => "View",
        "view_item" => "View Special Feature",
        "search_items" => "Search Special Features",
        "not_found" => "No Special Features Found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "No Special Features Found in Trash",
        "parent" => "Parent Special Feature",
        );

    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "cartoon-series/%series_name%", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "revisions" ),
        );
    register_post_type( "special-features", $args );

//==================================================================================
// -----------------------------------------------------
// Movies - movies
// -----------------------------------------------------
    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Movies",
        "singular_name" => "Movie",
        "menu_name" => "Movies",
        "all_items" => "All Movies",
        "add_new" => "Add New",
        "add_new_item" => "Add New Movie",
        "edit" => "Edit",
        "edit_item" => "Edit Movie",
        "new_item" => "New Movie",
        "view" => "View",
        "view_item" => "View Movie",
        "search_items" => "Search Movies",
        "not_found" => "NO Movies Found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "No Movies Found in Trash",
        "parent" => "Parent Movie"
        );

    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "movies", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "revisions" )
        );
    register_post_type( "movies", $args );

//==================================================================================
// -----------------------------------------------------
// Movie Special Features - movie-special-features
// -----------------------------------------------------
    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Movie Special Features",
        "singular_name" => "Movie Special Feature",
        "menu_name" => "Movie Special Features",
        "all_items" => "All Movie Special Features",
        "add_new" => "Add New",
        "add_new_item" => "Add New Movie Special Feature",
        "edit" => "Edit",
        "edit_item" => "Edit Movie Special Feature",
        "new_item" => "New Movie Special Feature",
        "view" => "View",
        "view_item" => "View Movie Special Feature",
        "search_items" => "Search Movie Special Features",
        "not_found" => "No Movie Special Features Found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "No Movie Special Features Found in Trash",
        "parent" => "Parent Movie Special Feature",
        );

    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "movies/%movie_name%", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "revisions" ),
        );
    register_post_type( "movie-special-features", $args );
```

Comment: [Do you have debugging enabled?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: @Milo is right, if you enable debugging it will tell you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Great...do I set the debug values in my functions.php or should I set it in the config file?

Comment: Well, would you look at that. CPT names can't be more than 20 characters. Makes sense! THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"movie-special-features" is longer than 20 chars. If you enable debug, you will get a message, these names are not allowed longer than 20 cars.
Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

You can enable the debug mode in you wp-config.php with

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: gladly found this quick! have to tell my client that "forschungseinrichtungen" is not possible. >.<